# Identifying enchantment before doing the actual enchantment

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

A while back I was playing minecraft online, and when working with the enchantment table I was able to see which enchantment I was about to get.

Now that I have a Tekkit Legends game I'm having the issue where I have no idea what the enchantment will be until I invest levels into it.

My question is then threefold:

1. Does vanilla minecraft tell you the enchantment beforehand, or was the server running a mod that adds this?
2. Does Tekkit Legends obfuscate the enchantment process?
3. And most importantly: How do I see which enchantment I'm about to get beforehand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This?  It's a feature added in Minecraft 1.8.  As far as I can tell, Tekkit Legends is a 1.7 modpack, so it doesn't have this feature.

[image: Picture of the enchantment table GUI]

Comment: Ah, that explains it, then. Any mod or the like that adds that functionality for 1.7?

Comment: @Jarmund try https://minecraft.curseforge.com/projects/et-futurum maybe?

Answer (score 0):

In "vanilla Minecraft" on the PC (Java version, not the Win10 edition), the enchanting table will show you the first type of enchantment before you actually enchant the item. There may be other enchantments included that are not shown to the player until the item is enchanted.